# Turning on NVIDIA propritary driver on Macbook Pro makes it hang on reboot

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers, boot

I have installed Freya on a Macbook Pro from 2010. Works great, except for one odd issue: When I turn on the propritary NVIDIA driver and reboot, the system hangs when starting up the X-server. The only thing that I can do then is to boot the root terminal from the recovery mode and remove all `nvidia-*` packages. So how can we make this work?

I think the GPU is a GT330M, but I don't know that for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same laptop and I tried to make it work with Ubuntu back then, but I guess your case is very similar.
AFAIK there is no way to get automated graphics switching to work as it is an Apple-designed hardware-based graphics switching solution which differs greatly from Nvidia's Optimus (that means `bumblebee` won't work).

I essentially boils down to two choices:

1. Leave your setup as is (intel driver)
2. Boot in non-EFI mode so that the MBP EFI will automatically switch to the Nvidia card (you won´t be able to use the power-efficient intel card that way untill reboot) by following the answer I outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340899/mac-book-pro-6-2-nvidia-graphics-suspend-dont-work)

Comment: My current setup has the Intel VGA controller turned on but also uses the open source driver for the NVIDIA GPU. Do you know whether its safe to disable the NVIDIA GPU, s.t. the energy consumption is lowered, and/or do you know how to do that?